# Usage of LLVM DependenceAnalysis Pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

For my own LLVM pass I need the results of the `llvm::DependenceAnalysis()` pass. I.e. I want the `DependenceInfo` object for some module/function.

I tried several approaches to get the pass to run the pass, however none worked so far.
Any hints on how to use `DependenceAnalysis` are welcome!

**First approach:**

I tried calling the `DependenceAnalysis().run()` function directly inside the `run()` function of my own pass.

```
// MAM is the ModuleAnalysisManager that is an argument to the run() function of my pass
FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM = MAM.getResult<FunctionAnalysisManagerModuleProxy>(M).getManager();
DependenceAnalysis depAnalysis;
llvm::DependenceInfo depInfo = depAnalysis.run(F, FAM);
```

When I run my pass I get an error from `opt`:
`opt: CommandLine Error: Option 'enable-fs-discriminator' registered more than once!`

I am not able to find the origin of this error message.

**Second approach:**
I added the `DependenceAnalysis()` pass directly to the `ModulePassManager`, to which I also add my own pass.

```
MPM.addPass(createModuleToFunctionPassAdaptor((DependenceAnalysis())))
```

This results in a compile erorr, since `DependenceAnalysis.run()` does not return a `PreservedAnalysis` object but a `DependenceInfo` object.

Comment: You want to [use an analysis](https://llvm.org/docs/NewPassManager.html#using-analyses).

Comment: @arnt thanks for the link. I used the `getAnalysis<>` function to obtain the result from the `FunctionAnalysisManager` by running:
`DependenceInfo depInfo = FAM.getResult<DependenceAnalysis>(F);`

However, I still get the error as in the first approach:
`CommandLine Error: Option 'enable-fs-discriminator' registered more than once!`

Comment: Your library's being loaded more than once. I got around that by linking statically. I'm sure you're smarter than I and can bend the dynamic linker to your will.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem was not only how I used the `DependenceAnalysis` but also some problems due to my linking of LLVM.

Getting the results of `DependenceAnalysis` is done by:

```
FunctionAnalysisManager &FAM = MAM.getResult<FunctionAnalysisManagerModuleProxy>(M).getManager();
DependencyInfo depInfo = FAM.getResult<DependenceAnalysis>(F);
```

Thanks to @arnt for pointing to the linking problem. Turns out I linked LLVM twice in `CMake`.